# In my exception, output is e, i am lookin for an exception string

Tags: python-3.x

```
except Exception as e:
        logger.warning(e)
        logger.warning(
            'following query process error:')
        logger.warning(file_SQL)
    return columns, rows
```

In my exception, output is e, i am lookin for an exception [error]:[error]

Comment: please provide clarity...  the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: generally not best practice for a catch all exception but you could do str(e) or e.args[0] but e.args[0] is not always a msg.